# video can't play in webview

Tags: android, video, webview

I put a web into webview.These is a video in the web.The video's format is mp4.I put the resource in the android project "assets" file.Now I can scan the web,but the video can't play.When I use this code mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/demo/html/demo.html"); ,the video can't play.If I use this code mWebView.loadUrl("http://v.youku.com/v_playlist/f16642432o1p0.html");,the video can play online.The demo.html can be opened by IE9 and chrome.My android edition is 3.1

```
    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webSettings = webview.getSettings();

    webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS); 
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true); 
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    webSettings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);

    webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/demo/html/demo.html");
    //webview.setWebChromeClient(new MyChromeClient());
    //webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebClient());
```

Comment: http://v.youku.com/v_playlist/f16642432o1p0.html  whether this link played in your default browser of android phone

Comment: what version of android your are testing

Comment: The version of android testing is 3.1.

Comment: v.youku.com/v_playlist/f16642432o1p0.html played in webview,not default browser.

Comment: i need to know whether the video is played in default browser of android... then we can know problem in code or from device end

Comment: It can play in default browser of android,but can't play in webview.So it makes me confused.

Comment: can you know problem in code or from device ?

Comment: From code side only... you try with HTML5 or try to use custom Webview and Webchrome client to play the video..

Answer (score 2):

Supposing you want to play any embedded video, you have to do two things:

1. In the android manifest, set `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`:

   ```
   <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
   <activity android:name=".Activity"
       android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   ```
2. What you've already done, in your main activity set:

   ```
   WebSettings w = webView.getSettings();      
   w.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
   ```

Hardware acceleration has to be activated in order to run on older Android devices, too, even though this option only appears in Android 3.0+. I guess you'd have to specify it somewhere in the code for Android 1.0-2.3.3, but it works fine this way if you're on 3.0+.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Worked, but the video is cut off. I can only see about 1/5th of the video and the rest is white screen. It works fine in Android 4.1, but not 3.1.